# Ruby On Rails Pagination - Maintain Sort Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, pagination, haml

I've been trying to learn Ruby & RoR for a while now but I'm stumped on a problem with maintaining sort on pagination links.  I've got the MVC architecture part down since I used similar architecture in PHP applications.  I've inherited an application from another group of developers that contains an error I need to correct.

On a page listing customers for a given user there is pagination to split the list into pages of 20.  Each column can be used to sort the table of data.  Once the page is sorted by an alternate column, clicking one of the pagination links will go to that page but revert the sort order to the default order.

So, the general idea is that i need to maintain the GET parameters of the current page (specifying the sort order) in the pagination links.

Some Sample URLs:

- Default: http://website.com/users/34/customers
- Sorted By Name: http://website.com/users/34/customers?customer%5Bsearch%5D%5Border_by%5D=first_name%2C+last_name&customer%5Bsearch%5D%5Border_direction%5D=ASC&customer%5Bsearch%5D%5Bname%5D=&customer%5Bsearch%5D%5Blocation_id%5D=&commit=Search
- Click Page 2: website.com/users/34/customers?page=2

Here are the code bits I think might be relevant.

Controller: controllers/customer_controller.rb

```
def index
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  @customer.user_id = (current_user.sales_director? || current_user.admin?) ? params[:user_id] : current_user.id
  @customer_pages, @customers = paginate  :customers,
                                        :joins => "INNER JOIN sources ON customers.source_id=sources.id INNER JOIN locations ON customers.location_id=locations.id",
                                        :select => "customers.*, sources.name AS source_name, locations.name AS location_name",
                                        :conditions => @customer.search_conditions,
                                        :per_page => 20,
                                        :order => @customer.search_order
end
```

View: views/customers/index.haml

```
%h1=User.find(params[:user_id]).full_name + "'s Customers"

.action_links
  - if !current_user.viewer?
    = link_to '+ Add New Customer', new_customer_path
    |
  = link_to 'View Follow Up Reminders', reminders_user_path(@user)

=render :partial => 'search_form'
%br/

- if @customer_pages.page_count > 1
  .pagination_links
    Go to page:
    = link_to '&lt;', pagination_prev_link if pagination_prev_link
    = pagination_links @customer_pages, :window_size => 5, :params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))
    = link_to '&gt;', pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count) if pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count)


- if @customers.size > 0
  = render :partial => 'search_results'
- else
  %p.no_results No customers matching your search criteria were found. Please try searching again.


- if @customer_pages.page_count > 1
  .pagination_links
    Go to page:
    = link_to '&lt;', pagination_prev_link if pagination_prev_link
    = pagination_links @customer_pages, :window_size => 5, :params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))
    = link_to '&gt;', pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count) if pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count)
```

I'd really appreciate any assistance I could get on how I could modify this to make this happen.  If any other code samples is necessary, just let me know.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE PREVIOUS AND NEXT PAGE LINKS (THESE WORK FINE).  HOPEFULLY THERE IS A WAY THAT CAN BE HELPFUL IN FINDING A WAY TO GET THE # LINKS TO WORK AS WELL.

```
#module ApplicationHelper

  # Took these next 2 methods from a blog post I found here: http://marklunds.com/articles/one/314
  # to help deal with a nested hash in params
  def flatten_hash(hash = params, ancestor_names = [])
    return if !hash 
    flat_hash = {}
    hash.each do |k, v|
      names = Array.new(ancestor_names)
      names << k
      if v.is_a?(Hash)
        flat_hash.merge!(flatten_hash(v, names))
      else
        key = flat_hash_key(names)
        key += "[]" if v.is_a?(Array)
        flat_hash[key] = v
      end
    end
    flat_hash
  end

  def flat_hash_key(names)
    names = Array.new(names)
    name = names.shift.to_s.dup 
    names.each do |n|
      name << "[#{n}]"
    end
    name
  end


  # pagination link helpers (because default one is kinda broken)
  def pagination_prev_link
    prev_link = params.clone
    if params[:page].to_i - 1 > 0
      prev_link[:page] = prev_link[:page].to_i - 1
      flatten_hash(prev_link)
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def pagination_next_link(max)
    next_link = params.clone
    if params[:page].to_i < max
      next_link[:page] = 1 if next_link[:page].to_i == 0
      next_link[:page] = next_link[:page].to_i + 1
      flatten_hash(next_link)
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: don't forget `will_paginate` can take arguments from a form with hidden fields (get request though)

Comment: Definitely shorten your original question and include the code for `pagination_links` helper. But, since this code has already proven itself to be hard to debug & maintain, I sincerely suggest you throw it all away after you fixed it and switch to will_paginate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is being used for pagination. If you could go with something like [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), they would take care of this sort of thing for you.

If that's too much refactoring, here's something to try with your current setup.

It looks like this `:params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))` is doing what you're looking for already. The problem is that it's only for the page number links and not the previous/next links. Do the numbered pagination links work or are they broken too?

If I were you I'd try changing the next and previous links to something like this and see if it works.

```
= link_to '&lt;', pagination_prev_link(:params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))) if pagination_prev_link
...
= link_to '&gt;', pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count, :params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))) if pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count)
```

If that doesn't work maybe you can find out where `pagination_prev_link` and `pagination_next_link` and defined and post that code.

UPDATE:

I don't really understand what the need for the `flatten_hash` method is. So I'd try it without it. Also, might as well be more explicit about the hash parameters, just in case, even though you shouldn't have to be.

```
= pagination_links @customer_pages, {:window_size => 5, :params => params.dup.delete(:page)}, {}
```

If that doesn't work you could try passing in some parameters manually just to see if it works at all.

```
= pagination_links @customer_pages, {:params => {:test_param => 1}}, {}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing about the :params entry in the numbered links.  Unfortunately, it doesn't actually append the existing parameters to the numbered links.  The numbered links are the priority right now.  I think if I figure those out I can get the prev and next ones working.  And if I can't, I am willing to just remove them and leave only the numbered links.  I did a search through the application code and "pagination_links" is not defined within the application, so it must be part of ruby or rails (i think).

Comment: Here is what it looks like is being used for pagination. It has the source available on that page as well, so hopefully that helps diagnose the issue. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PaginationHelper/pagination_links

Comment: It turns out that the "prev page" and "next page" < > links worked just fine. They actually maintain the parameters.  The numbered links are the only problems.  I will update my question with the code for the pagination_prev_link function.

Comment: Wow, `pagination_links` hasn't been in Rails since 1.2.6. That's really old in the Rails world. What version of Rails is your app running? I'll update my answer with something else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I ended up knowing enough about what I was doing to come up with a bit of a hack of a solution... but it seems to be working as expected.

New function was added to application helper:

```
  def pagination_page_link(p)
    page_link = params.clone
    page_link[:page] = p
    flatten_hash(page_link)
  end
```

The following was used in the view file twice to replace the original lines outputting the numbered links.

```
- if @customer_pages.page_count > 1
  .pagination_links
    Go to page:
    = link_to '&lt;', pagination_prev_link if pagination_prev_link
    - @customer_pages.each do |page|
      = page.number if @customer_pages.current_page.number == page.number
      = link_to page.number, pagination_page_link(page.number) unless @customer_pages.current_page.number == page.number
    -#= pagination_links @customer_pages, :window_size => 5, :params => flatten_hash(params.dup.delete(:page))
    = link_to '&gt;', pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count) if pagination_next_link(@customer_pages.page_count)
```